# Override a SiteMapProvider / Deploy this with VS2010

Tags: deployment, visual-studio

I am tryin to override the SiteMapProvider "CurrentNavigation" in nightandday.master.
I got the code to override the class, but i am not sure how i handle the deploy process.
A colleague told me that there is a way to deploy that using a "Feature" in VS2010.
So i created a new Feature, bound CustomSitemapProvider.cs to it, and deployed everything..
As you probably expect now.. nothing changed.
Do i have to change the Deployment Type? Or am i on the completely wrong track now?

Edit:
I tried that with the Feature now...
I got a elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" Sequence="90" ControlAssembly="CustomSitemapProviderFeature, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=841c5c559877013a" ControlClass="CustomSitemapProviderFeature.CustomSitemapProvider"/>
</Elements>
```

And just a "Test Feature"..:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomSitemapProviderFeature
{
    class CustomSitemapProvider : WebControl
    {

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            string helloAlert = "alert('Hello, world!');";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "popup", helloAlert, true);
            Label lab = new Label();
            lab.Text = "TEST";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(lab);

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }



    }
}
```

Well .. I am able to deploy that... but nothing happens... I am not able to run my code through a Feature... My plan is to override the whole SitemapProvider through such a class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to deploy a custom sitemap provider as a SharePoint feature.

I created an empty class library project in Visual Studio, added there my public class extending *PortalSiteMapProvider*, made the DLL available in the GAC, and manually added this line in the web.config file of the SharePoint web application, inside the *<sitemap><providers>* block:

```
<add name="CustomSiteMapProviderName" NavigationType="Current" type="_Fully qualified class name_, _Class library name without the dll extension_, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=_The key token for the dll_" />
```

In your class you need to override these two methods:

- **GetChildNodes** - Here is where your custom business logic goes.
- **Initialize** - To specify the name which will be used to identify your custom provider in the *SiteMap.Providers* collection. Something like this:

  ```
  public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
  {
      if (config == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("config is null");

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
          name = "CustomSiteMapProviderName";

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["description"]))
      {
          config.Remove("description");
          config.Add("description", "Brief description");
      }

      base.Initialize(name, config);
  }
  ```

And then you can use your new provider in any navigation control.

Comment: Thank you Xavier for your answer but i really need a deployable solution for this..

Comment: Me too... so I kept looking, and today I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649108.aspx It explains how to register the new provider in the section *Configuring and Registering the Site Map Provider*, by using the SPWebConfigModification class.